# Search Gmail for emails from specific address using single character wildcard

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I have a Gmail account with my own person email address like `myname@myemailid.com` . This all works fine. Backed up in my Gmail account I had other email ids with other characters/names before the `@myemailid.com` . I know that these emails are backed up in my Gmail account but I have forgotten what names I used. How can I do a search for a backed up email that starts with 2 characters, as in `**@myemailid.com` ?

Is it possible to search for an email address that only has 2 character before the @?

Answer (score 1):

Try it that way in the search box:

```
to:(@myemailid.com) NOT to:(myname@myemailid.com)
```

It doesn't exactly search for 2 characters before your @ but it excludes your current address from the results for @myemailid.com

Answer (score -1):

You should try creating a Filter. Enter @myemaild.com in the from and do a search. That will yield all results from that email.